# Apache Ignite and SASL

Tags: ignite

I'm new to Apache Ignite.So Ignite supports client authentication like SASL(Simple Authentication and security layer) to use with memcached client?

If there is no support for SASL, please point me on how to achieve client authentication.

Can someone please assist me in this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for Memcache client authentication. If you want to secure connection to Ignite, you should switch to the native Ignite API and implement the authentication mechanisms in a plugin (see [1], for example).

There are also some vendors, like GridGain [2], that already provide such implementations in their paid offerings.

[1] http://smartkey.co.uk/development/securing-an-apache-ignite-cluster/

[2] https://gridgain.readme.io/docs/security-and-audit